# Cordova 3.5 embedded webview with plugins

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea, webview

I have an existing native Android app to which I'm adding a cordova webview.
This is in the new gradle project format with Intellij.
I've successfully gotten the cordova activity loaded, and opens as expected. 
I added the webview by following the [cordova docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews).

Now I'd like to use some of the plugins available but can't find a way to add them to the project.
Since this isn't a cordova generated project, plugman doesn't work. I've tried copying the JS and Java files for the plugins I'm interested in to my source dir but that results in various errors.

e.g. require is undefined, when this happened, I added requirejs to the webview's index.html
and it moved on to

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "cordova/exec" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded cordova.js:8
Failed to load resource file:///android_asset/www/scripts/cordova_plugins.js
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1191
Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
```

How do I get a plugin working with this?

**EDIT:**

I am manually moving stuff around.

1. This has to be put into an existing project which uses gradle for building.
2. Using cordova create generates a project in the old ANT format.
3. I followed the docs on embedding a WebView in an existing project (see the link above), but it doesn't mention any of the JavaScript files. So I just copied cordova.js from the android platform directory.
4. Like wise, I download the plugins I wanted, copied their JavaScript files, added the feature to build.xml and copied their Java files to my src directory.

I didn't know about cordova_plugins.js or that cordova prepare generates them.

Comment: Not very clear how do you setup build.
Currently `cordova prepare android` creates files `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js` to the `file:///android_asset/www/` folder.
Do you manually move stuff around?

Comment: @codevision edited in response to your questions.

Comment: did you get the answer for this @zcourts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Plugman to manage your plugins in the custom built Cordova WebView.

Please remove all your existing plugins and read them using plugman.

```
plugman install --platform android --project <proj> --plugin org.apache.cordova.battery-status --www <proj>/assets/www/scripts
```

where the `<proj>` is the folder where you main project is created,
Alternatively you could use --www parameter which allows you to specify where root of web application is stored. Example:

```
plugman install --platform android --project <proj> --plugin org.apache.cordova.battery-status --www <proj>/assets/www/scripts
```

[Plugman reference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html)

**EDIT**

If you have highly customized project, you could create empty Cordova project where you add
plugins, and copy `cordova_plugins.js` from this project to `assets\www\scripts`, Cordova should pickup these files. If you have your plugins JS files not in the `assets\www\scripts\plugins\` folder, but instead of that in `assets\www\plugins` you have to modify content of `cordova_plugins.js` like that

```
module.exports = [
.....
{
    "file": "../plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/InAppBrowser.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser",
    "clobbers": [
        "window.open"
    ]
},
...
]
```

Comment: plugman doesn't work with this as I mentioned in the question, plugman says "current directory is not a cordova based project"

Comment: Added more ways to add plugins

Answer (score 0):

Here is some input on how I came though,
I am in a similar position like the OP, embedding a Cordova Web View in my Native Android Application.
After executing
`plugman install --platform android --project <proj> --plugin org.apache.cordova.battery-status --www <proj>/assets/www/scripts`

What happens is you get a new 'Cordova' folder in your original 'main' Folder, (Where your AndroidManifest.xml is). Besides that, there is the 'src' folder with the code you actually need generated.

What I did, was copying the org folder from src to the 'java' folder. And everything worked.