# how to add plugin without cli in cordova 3.5.0 iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am not using cli for my cordova project ,i got the cordova 3.5.0 project from there site and integrated with my project.All the custom plugins created by me is working fine.But the API's like device is not accessible.I have added the CDVDevice to config.xml but still i can't able to access the device object.
So please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly working the Cordova requires you to have `cordova_plugins.js` file near the `cordova.js`. That file contains registration of the JS API.

The easiest part is use Plugman to install plugins inside your custom project, that way, it will handle all work on creation of `cordova_plugins.js`.

Official Cordova documentation for the [Plugman](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html)

See the possible related answer [Cordova 3.5 embedded webview with plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557841/cordova-3-5-embedded-webview-with-plugins/25568499#25568499) where I put more insights about how you could modify `cordova_plugins.js` in case you desperately need this, but I would recommend you to use Plugman.

Comment: Thanks.....Currently in my project i am using cordova 2.7 version.Now we have a reuirement to upgrade cordova to 3.5 version.How i can achieve that?I tried creating a cordova project using cli and added the cordovaLib project alone to my old native project ,but nothing working.Custom plugins also not working.Please help me on this .....