# how to install plugins in cordova in embedded webview section

Tags: cordova, webview

i need to install plugins in my android application that is using cordova webview. if i am trying to install plugins as i usually do in cordova projects i got an error its not an cordova projects

{Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project}

i have taken the reference from 
: [Cordova 3.5 embedded webview with plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557841/cordova-3-5-embedded-webview-with-plugins)

And now i can see installed plugins but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that myself ,

You can do that with plugman

```
plugman install --platform android --project /path/to/your/project --plugin org.apache.cordova.file --www /path/to/your/project/assets/www
```

This will install any plugin in your native android project
 using phonegap web view .

Comment: Thank you very much! The documentation on embedded WebView lacks that super important thing!